# jQuery Ui Tooltip Not Working on Raphaël.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, raphael

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tsa1wt1f/) and let me know why the tooltip is not showing on the path on mouse over?

```js
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>
$(function () {
    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
    var d = "M90,90l-80,-20L50,5L90,90";
    var tri = paper.path(d).attr({
            "fill": "yellow",
            "stroke-width": 5,
            "stroke-linejoin": "round",
            "title": "Show Me The Tooltip!"
    });
    $(tri).tooltip();
});
```

Comment: It's working as expected (at least with FF38) Could you describe your problem?

Comment: Hi blgt , can you see the jQuery Ui Tooltip?

Comment: No, but that's because you haven't included one, you only have the regular tooltip which looks fine (maybe you just need to style it?). As far as i can tell `$(tri)` is a Raphael object, not a valid selector